# When does $\frac{{E[{X_1}]}}{{E[{X_2}]}} > 1$ imply $\frac{{E[X_1^2]}}{{E[X_2^2]}} > \frac{{E[{X_1}]}}{{E[{X_2}]}}$?

Tags: probability-theory

There are two random variables ${X_1},{X_2} \in [a,b]$  where $a > 0$. When does $\frac{{E[{X_1}]}}{{E[{X_2}]}} > 1$  imply $\frac{{E[X_1^2]}}{{E[X_2^2]}} > \frac{{E[{X_1}]}}{{E[{X_2}]}}$ ?